# Laravel Paginate not working

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I was trying to paginate some data with Query builder with the following query.

```
public function productSearch(Request $request)
{
     $name = $request->name; 
     $products = DB::table('products')                  
         ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$name%")             
         ->paginate(4);

     return view('product',compact('products');
}
```

But when I tried to show the pagination in the view page with the following line

```
{{ $products->links() }}
```

It shows

> Method links does not exist

What could the possible error be since the pagination does not show?

Comment: try this
`$products = DB::table('products')                  
         ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$name%");
$products->paginate(4);`

Comment: Do foreach loop in view before you use `{{ $products->links() }}`. Please follow this link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

Comment: Is there any result in `$products` in the controller? What do you get for `dd($products)` ?

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using? Run `dd($products);` in your controller method and show us the result.

Answer (score 2):

2 types to print pagination link in laravel -
Try with -

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
public function productSearch(Request $request)
{
     $name = $request->name; 
     $products = DB::table('products')                  
         ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$name%")             
         ->paginate(4);

     return view('product',['products' => $products]);
}
```

In View -

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <h4>{{ $product['name'] }}</h5> <br>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

1st type to defined laravel pagination link -

```
   {{ $products->links() }}
```

And 2nd type to defined laravel pagination link -

```
   {{ $products->render(); }}
```

Note - Also you missed in your code -> return view('product',compact('products')`)`; in return view('product',compact('products');
[image: Desired output -]

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution.
**Just change your return view option**

```
return view('product')->with('products', $products);
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Change to :

```
return view('product',compact('products'));
```

In View page try :

```
{{$products->render()}}
```

Comment: same problem I'm facing after your change

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller:

```
return view('product',compact('products');
```

In your View:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
  {{ $product->name }}
@endforach

{{ $products->links() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
{{ $products->render() }}
```